# How to prevent MenuButton from closing when clicking on the CheckMenuItem (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, fxml, auto-close, popupmenubutton

I'm new with Java, I would like to know how to prevent MenuButton popup from closing when I click on the item, I tried the following function, which I found on this site, but does not seem to do anything. I need this in order to make a clone of my C# application whit the purpose of learning Java.

```
@FXML
private MenuButton menuButton;

@FXML
    void initialize() {
        CheckMenuItem menuButtonItem1 = new CheckMenuItem("Item 1");
        CheckMenuItem menuButtonItem2 = new CheckMenuItem("Item 2");
        CheckMenuItem menuButtonItem3 = new CheckMenuItem("Item 3");
        menuButtonItem1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
           e.consume();
    }
});
        menuButtonItem2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
           e.consume();
    }
});
        menuButtonItem3.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
           e.consume();
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `CustomMenuItem` class provides a `setHideOnClick()` method that will handle this. In order to use it, you'll wrap a standard `Node` in this `CustomMenuItem`:

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("Item 1");
CustomMenuItem customMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(checkBox);
customMenuItem.setHideOnClick(false);
```

Below is a full example for you to try:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CheckMenuKeepOpen extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Create the MenuButton
        MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton("Click Me");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            // In order to keep the menu open when selecting a CheckBox, we need to wrap it in a CustomMenuItem
            CustomMenuItem menuItem = new CustomMenuItem(new CheckBox("Item #" + i));

            // This method is pretty obvious; it keeps the menu open when selecting this item.
            menuItem.setHideOnClick(false);
            menuButton.getItems().add(menuItem);
        }

        root.getChildren().add(menuButton);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish to thank you for your quick help.And wish you also a good day.

Answer (score 0):

We found using custom menu item would lose the styling of normal menu items. Instead we solved by using a Menu (i.e. a sub menu) with no items in which other than arrows to the right looks identical to a normal menu item but does not close when clicked. Then finally used css to remove the arrow to the right.